# How to use ionic popover like page tour with ionic angular?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Is there any way or any framework or any particular ionic component to implement this below kind of feature.

[image]

Here is what I want:

When I open the component for first time the pop over automatically appears over a button ( like we have page tour in websites ). On click on GOT IT it will dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

Use the popover component (https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) with

```
ionViewDidEnter(){ }
```

As the popover is most of the time triggered by a click, you'll need to use javascript to "fake" a click :

```
ionViewDidEnter(){ 
let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('button') as HTMLElement;
  element.click();
}
```

And then you create your onClick() method for your button to present the popover.

Comment: How would you prevent the actual action of the button from being called? OP wants to highlight the button and present help for it. Totally agree that I think the popover component is the way to go, but how to trigger it and highlight the specific element. Currently investigating the same thing.